# Extract certain values from a list

Tags: python, list

I'm pretty new to Python and only want to extract the city for these clients' addresses:

```
clients = ["Peter, Calle Fantasia 15, Madrid", "Robert, Plaza de Perdas 2, 
            Sevilla", "Paul, Calle Polo, Madrid", "Francesco, Plaza de Opo I, Segovia"]
```

Can someone help? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Is the city always the third part of `<name>, <street>, <city>`. Try to `split` each string.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a list comprehension, and keep the last element in each string starting from the lst `,` onwards.

For that use [`string.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) setting `,` as a separator, which will split each string whenever there is a comma, slice the resulting lists keeping the last element, and use [`string.strip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) to remove leading white spaces:

```
clients = ["Peter, Calle Fantasia 15, Madrid", "Robert, Plaza de Perdas 2, 
            Sevilla", "Paul, Calle Polo, Madrid", "Francesco, Plaza de Opo I, Segovia"]

[i.split(',')[-1].strip() for i in clients]
# ['Madrid', 'Sevilla', 'Madrid', 'Segovia']
```

---

For more details on the methods used above, I'd suggest you give a look at:

- [string — Common string operations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html)
- [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Comment: None @prashantrana :)

Answer (score 2):

If the elements of `clients` are always of the format `"name, address, city"`, you can [split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) it like so:

```
# List comprehension, splits each element of client on commas,
# then takes the final element (stripping any whitespace)
clients = [client.split(',')[-1].strip() for client in clients]
```

```
>>> print(clients)

['Madrid', 'Sevilla', 'Madrid', 'Segovia']
```

Answer (score 0):

without using list comprehension

```
clients = ["Peter, Calle Fantasia 15, Madrid", "Robert, Plaza de Perdas 2, Sevilla", "Paul, Calle Polo, Madrid", "Francesco, Plaza de Opo I, Segovia"]
list_of_cities =[]
for i in clients:
    index_last_comma = 0
    for j in range(len(i)-1,0,-1):
        if i[j]==',':
            index_last_comma  = j
            break
    city = i[j+1:len(i)].strip()
    list_of_cities.append(city)

print(list_of_cities)
# output ['Madrid', 'Sevilla', 'Madrid', 'Segovia']
```